# productivity power tools 2017 classes are not visible any more

Tags: visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

After install of productivity power tools 2017 the C#  classes are not seen by MainWindow.xaml. Also the design is not visible. I have uninstalled the PPT, but the problem remains. What else should be cleaned or changed?

**UPDATE**

Rebuilding the solution fixed it...

Comment: Off-topic because OP has answered his own question in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you found, rebuilding the solution brought the tools back to their normal state.